# ajax url path is not defined, how to get the wordpress file path in ajax url?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

Getting error on ajax URL path in wordpress. It's working on localhost, But it's not working on the server. And my upload-file.php is located at **domainname.com/wp-content/themes/mytheme/upload-file.php** How can I define the URL path jquery ajax? Please help me to solve the issue.

Here is my code sample:

```
$.ajax({
     url:'upload-file.php',
     method:"POST",
     data: form_data,
     contentType: false,
     cache: false,
     processData: false,
```

Comment: I just edit the answer please try 2nd

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery Ajax File Upload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2320069/jquery-ajax-file-upload)

Answer (score 2):

Use wp_localize_script for ajax in wordpress. The URL of the WordPress admin-ajax.php file, where the data to be sent for processing.

```
//add in function.php
function ajax_script() {
    wp_enqueue_script( 'ajax_operation_script', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/script.js', array('jquery'), '1.0.0', true );
    wp_localize_script( 'ajax_operation_script', 'myAjax', array( 'ajaxurl' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php', 'relataive' )));  
    wp_enqueue_script( 'ajax_operation_script' );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'ajax_script' );
```

The Ajax action hook called wp_ajax_. You need to hook a custom function into it which will be executed during the Ajax call.

```
//add in function.php
add_action('wp_ajax_upload_file', 'upload_file');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_upload_file', 'upload_file');

function upload_file(){
    parse_str($_POST['form_data'], $my_array_of_vars);
    print_r($my_array_of_vars);
    die;
}
```

Ajax Code.

```
$.ajax({
    url: myAjax.ajaxurl,
    method:"POST",
    data : {action: 'upload_file',
    form_data:form_data 
    },
    contentType: false,
    cache: false,
    processData: false
```

Comment: Thank you dear, I have a doubt.. What about admin-ajax.php? is that upload-file.php?

Comment: No it's not a upload-flile.php it's just call your ajaxfile action.

Comment: Just follow this https://medium.com/techcompose/how-to-use-ajax-precisely-in-wordpress-custom-themes-dc61616720a8 why worpdress use nopriv function to call every ajax call

Comment: Nopriv it's handle your ajax request

Comment: 1- admin-ajax.php is core wordpress file to run AJAX calls from the web-browser.  2- The Ajax action hook called wp_ajax_. You need to hook a custom function into it which will be executed during the Ajax call.

Comment: In your ajax request I pass extra attribute action:upload_file within data. And I create a function 'upload_file' and attached with wp_ajax. upload_file function is used to execute the ajax call.